# Can't Add a new Storyboard to my Single View Template App

Tags: ios, objective-c

Essentially, I need to know how to add new storyboards to the template. I want a main screen to split off into 1 other screen then split into 4 other screens. See Below

Menu Screen -> Secondary Menu Screen -v

```
                           -> Screen 1          
                           -> Screen 2
                           -> Screen 3
                           -> Screen 4
```

I'm not sure how to add these storyboards to my project and im not familiar with the "View Controller" hierachy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou

Comment: This is a very basic question. I strongly suggest you work through a tutorial like `Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad` from Stanford on iTunesU. This covers the `Model/View/Controller` concept and will help you understand view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this -  If you want to do ios development there is no escaping learning about ViewControllers. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html

You need only one storyboard and you can add as many view controllers as needed.

Comment: Thanks, at least I know what im reading is going to help. There is so much rubbish on the internet.